# pandas rolling on specific column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying something very simple, seemingly at least which is to do a rolling sum on a column of a dataframe. See minimal example below :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Col1": [10, 20, 15, 30, 45],
                   "Col2": [13, 23, 18, 33, 48],
                   "Col3": [17, 27, 22, 37, 52]})
df['dt'] = pd.date_range("2020-01-01", "2020-01-05")
```

| index | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | dt. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 | 13 | 17 | 2020-01-01 |
| 1 | 20 | 23 | 27 | 2020-01-02 |
| 2 | 15 | 18 | 22 | 2020-01-03 |
| 3 | 30 | 33 | 37 | 2020-01-04 |
| 4 | 45 | 48 | 52 | 2020-01-05 |

If I run

```
df['sum2']=df['Col1'].rolling(window="3d", min_periods=2, on=df['dt']).sum()
```

then instead of getting what I'm hoping which is a rolling sum on column 1, I get this traceback. If I switch the index to the dt field value it works if I removed the `on=df['dt']` param. I've tried `on='dt'` also with no luck.

This is the error message I get :

```
...
ValueError: invalid on specified as 0   2020-01-01
1   2020-01-02
2   2020-01-03
3   2020-01-04
4   2020-01-05
Name: dt, dtype: datetime64[ns], must be a column (of DataFrame), an Index or None
```

Anything I'm overlooking?
thanks!

Comment: Maybe settings `dt` as index will help: `df.set_index('dt')['Col1'].rolling(window="3d", min_periods=2).sum().reset_index(drop=True)`.

Comment: that would work, but I'm trying to get rid of resetting the index in the first place.. but thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
df['sum2'] = df.rolling(window="3d", min_periods=2, on='dt')['Col1'].sum()
print(df)

# Output:
   Col1  Col2  Col3         dt  sum2
0    10    13    17 2020-01-01   NaN
1    20    23    27 2020-01-02  30.0
2    15    18    22 2020-01-03  45.0
3    30    33    37 2020-01-04  65.0
4    45    48    52 2020-01-05  90.0
```

Your error is to extract the columns `Col1` at first so the column `dt` does not exist when `rolling`.

```
>>> df['Col1']  # the column 'dt' does not exist anymore.
0    10
1    20
2    15
3    30
4    45
Name: Col1, dtype: int64
```